# Barplot with frequency of values for every column in a data frame

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to visualize the frequency of every unique values in each column of my data frame ("ad2") using barplots.

My ideia was that every barplot would represent a unique column from my data frame. Each bar plot would count the frequency of every unique value, including NA's, and each value would have different colors. It would look something like the this:

[image]

```
colors <- c("steelblue", "coral", "palegreen", "purple")

plot_frequency_barplot <- function(column, col_name) {
freq_table <- table(column, useNA = "always")`your text`
barplot(freq_table, main = col_name, beside = FALSE, xlab = "Values", ylab = "Frequency", col =      colors)
}

for (col_name in names(ad2)) {
cat("Creating a barplot for Column:", col_name, "\n")
plot_frequency_barplot(ad2[[col_name]], col_name)
}
```

I tried this code but it still does not return me stacked columns.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The photo of the bar graph you posted appears to have been created with the `ggplot2` package, so if you want to create a similar graph, it may be valuable to employ that package. See an overview of that package [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Also if you could, could you post a subset of your data, following instructions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example. It will help responders better help you fix your code with the data you intend to use.